# how to connect JButtons from a list to actionListener

Tags: java, list, actionlistener

I have a dynamic number of JButtons in a list and need help to connect them to the actionListener

I first create the buttons based on a list called alt:

```
for(int i =0;i<alt.size();i++) {
        JButton button = new JButton (alt.get(i));
        button.addActionListener(this); 
        buttonList.add(button);
    }
```

Later I add the buttons like this

```
private void gui(List<JButton> bList) {

    f = new JFrame("window");
    f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());    
    f.setVisible(true); 

    JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel();
    buttonPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(buttonPane, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

    for(int i =0;i<bList.size();i++) {
        buttonPane.add(bList.get(i));
    }
    f.add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
 }
```

I know there will never be more than 4 buttons. So how can I connect to the right button in the ActionListener ? without them being declared outside the scope of gui or  individually named?

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


        if(e.getSource() == ?) {  
        } else if (e.getSource() == ?) {
        } else if (e.getSource() == ?){
        }else if (e.getSource() == ?){
        }
}
```

Comment: What are these buttons *doing*? Is it an action that can be with dealt logically by a dynamically sized list? For example, print(1), print(2), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your buttons are doing actions, you should implement separate Action Listeners for each button, otherwise in your `e.getSource() == ?` the `?` should be a JButton instance, for example : `e.getSource() == bList.get(0)`